# Can i eat on a table which alcohol was consumed on?

Tags: alcohol

I am living in a dorm with a shared kitchen, and my flatmates drank alcohol on the kitchen table, can i still eat on that table?

Comment: It's fine as long as you don't intake/intermix alcohol.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Please elaborate: do you mean eat and sit with them while they are drinking? Is the alcohol still present when you sit on the table? Are they Muslims? etc. .... this questions clearly needs more inptut.

Comment: No I wasn't sitting with them and they are not Muslims, I was asking if they drank on the table already and cleaned up everything on the table and after its been cleaned I ate on that table so is it permissible to eat on it after it has been cleaned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be no problem as long as the area and table you sit at is clean or cleaned.

Comment: Thank you so much